# Is there a way to change the Business Date through BLC code?

Tags: acumatica

Can I change the business date through BLC code?  I know it's in the AccessInfo DAC (AccessInfo.businessDate).

Thanks...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The static `PXContext` has a public static method called `SetBusinessDate`, You can use that method to change the Business Date.

```
public static void SetBusinessDate(DateTime? date)
{
    PXContext.PXIdentity.BusinessDate = date;
}
```

You can simply call PXContext.SetBusinessDate method and force a page refresh after that, otherwise the UI will still show the old business date.

```
var YOUR_NEW_BUSINESS_DATE = new DateTime(2022,01,01);
PXContext.SetBusinessDate(YOUR_NEW_BUSINESS_DATE);
throw new PXRefreshException();
```

Comment: I don't understand.  Do I re-create that method, then call it somewhere?  Or do I call SetBusinessDate - is that a method available somewhere?   I tried PXContext.SetBusinessDate - and it gives me a syntax error:  "cannot assign to SetBusinessDate because it is a method group".  No idea what that means.

Comment: @pmfith I have updated the answer with an example